# Accessing active directory from C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group

I am trying to access directory in XXX domain from my console application.

```
             DirectoryEntry oDE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=XXXX,DC=myDomain,DC=com");

            using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(oDE))
            {
                ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
                ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName");

                ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))";

                SearchResultCollection results = ds.FindAll();

                foreach (SearchResult result in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}",
                        result.Properties["name"][0].ToString(),
                        result.Properties["userPrincipalName"][0].ToString());
                }
            }
```

when the line SearchResultCollection results = ds.FindAll(); executes I receive the error "There is no such object on the server."

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Do I need to supply any authentication to access the directory entry?

Comment: Did you make sure to change the other 3 parts in the LDAP Uri as well? If your domain is DomainXXX.lan; it needs to be DC=DomainXXX,DC=lan

Comment: External Domain = XXXX.com
MyDomain = test.com

DirectoryEntry oDE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=XXX.com,DC=test,DC=com");

I think this is the way.

Comment: No, that's not correct. If your servername = DomainServerA.SomeCompany.net, your Uri would be: LDAP://DC=DomainServerA,DC=SomeCompany,DC=net

Comment: Actually I want to access and validate a user exists in the following domain's AD from within my console application.
ldap://Test1.Test2.gov.lk/

if so how is the Directory Entry can be created?

Comment: LDAP://DC=Test1,DC=Test2,DC=gov,DC=lk

Comment: Yes I tried as you mentioned now get the following exception.
A referral was returned from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so short resume of our 'chat' in the comments:

Your current problem is caused because you don't format the LDAP uri correctly.

LDAP URI Buildup = "LDAP://DC="

followed by your server uri (e.g. Test1.Test2.gov.lk) where you replace the '.' with ',DC='

So, Test1.Test2.gov.lk becomes 'LDAP://DC=Test1,DC=Test2,DC=gov,DC=lk'

I can't help you with your followup problem; I suggest creating a new question for that.

Good Luck,

Nick.